# How to configure "tomcat7-maven-plugin" in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am trying to add a tomcat7-maven-plugin dependency to `pom.xml` file and getting an error.
I am following the instructions on [tomcat.apache.org](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html).

[image]

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'configuration'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":type, "http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":classifier, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scope, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":systemPath, "http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":exclusions, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":optional}' is expected.
```

**My full `pom.xml` config**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tastyminerals.poems</groupId>
    <artifactId>poemcollection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                <server>localhost</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            </configuration>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Tomcat7-maven-plugin should be declared as a plugin, it is not a dependency.
You can't add a configuration tag to a dependency as indicated by the error.

Thus something like the following should work :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tastyminerals.poems</groupId>
<artifactId>poemcollection</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
            <server>localhost</server>
            <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<...>
   </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

i also face the issue, when i deploy the spring web mvc application run as server

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-r1756463</version>
</dependency>
```

this works for me